# How to change background color in my Tao subtheme

Tags: 7, theming

We have a custom sub theme built on Tao and I tried adding

`body {
  color:#fff;
  background:#333;
  }`

to the `style.css` file, but to no avail. In Chrome dev tools I started inspecting elements and changing their backgrounds individually, but I cannot figure out how to change the background color for all divs, form elements, blocks, etc without some super complicated CSS.

I'm trying to avoid doing this, if possible:

```
#main-content {
  background: #333;
}

#page {
  background: #333;
}

#page-title {
  background: #333;
}

#branding {
  background: #666;
}

div.limiter {
  background: transparent;
}

div.region {
  background: #333;
}

span.fieldset-title {
  background: #333;
}

div.tabs {
  background: #333;
}

fieldset.collapsible {
  background: #333;
}

.collapsed .fieldset-legend a {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Further, when implementing this code, I cannot get some divs to change color, for instance `<div id="page-title">`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of the theme. If your can´t see any change after apply this, there are two possible reasons:

```
body {
  color:#fff;
  background:#333;
  }
```

1. There are other elements, like divs, upon your body elemnts.
2. The change that you made is not reflected on your site. Check if you are working in the correct css file. If it is a .sass file, maybe it needs to compile. Other reason for that, is for the cache, try to delete by going to `admin/config/development/performance`

Good luck!.

Comment: I'm seeing my changes. I have compressed JS/CSS turned off for development. You're right, there are all kinds of divs on top of the body element. What I don't understand is that it looks like all their backgrounds are set to transparent.